# Webscraping with Python3 - Ignoring Duplicate Attribute Errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, web-scraping, html-parsing

I would like to use Python 3 to create a web scraping application. The website that I am trying to scrape contains invalid xhtml - in that it has tags with duplicate attribute names.

I would like to use xml.dom.minidom to parse the fetched pages. Because of the duplicate attribute names, the content does not parse, and I am presented with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 45, in <module>
    scraper.list()
  File "scraper.py", line 34, in list
    dom = parseString(response.text)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1970, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 925, in parseString
    return builder.parseString(string)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: duplicate attribute: line 2, column 43
```

I want to ignore this error and parse the document anyways. I have no control over the icoming html data. What can I do?

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString


class Scraper:

    def __init__( self ):

        pass

    def list(self,pages=1):

        response = requests.get('http://example.com')

        dom = parseString(response.text)

        print(dom.toxml)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    scraper = Scraper()

    scraper.list()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way: switch to [`BeautifulSoup` HTML parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). It's quite good at parsing non well-formed or broken HTML and, depending on the [underlying parser library](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use), can be [less or more lenient](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")  # or use "html5lib", or "lxml"
```